# not able pass parameter value in crystal report

Tags: crystal-reports

i have a code like this for passing parameter filed value into crystal report.

```
Dim projectreportds As New ProjectRptnew -**this s dataset name**
        If ds.Tables.Count > 0 Then
            projectreportds.Tables(0).Merge(ds.Tables(0))
            Dim rpt As New ProjectReportNew-**this s report name**
            rpt.SetParameterValue("ExhbitionName", cmbExhibition.Text)
            Dim objrpt As New frmrptengine(AppPath & "\reports\ProjectReportNew.rpt", projectreportds)
            objrpt.ShowDialog()
        End If
```

but if am running this code am asking parameter value.what changes i have to make in my code..

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Set App = CreateObject("CrystalRuntime.Application")
report= "c:\report.rpt"
Set rep = app.OpenReport(report) 

For i = 1 To rpt.Database.Tables.Count
        Print rpt.Database.Tables(i).name
        If rpt.Database.Tables(i).name = "YOUR_TABLE_NAME" Then         
          //first table login
          rpt.Database.Tables(i).SetLogonInfo "YOUR_SERVER_NAME","YOUR_DATABASE_PATH",Username.Abbreviated,Password 
        Else
          //second table login
          rpt.Database.Tables(i).SetLogonInfo "YOUR_SERVER_NAME","YOUR_DATABASE_PATH",Username.Abbreviated,Password 
        End If
    Next
```

YOUR_TABLE_NAME= name of the table, you can find it under "Database" menù, "Database Expert" ->"Selected Tables"

YOUR_SERVER_NAME= the server name of source database

YOUR_DATABASE_PATH= the complete path of the source database

Username.Abbreviated= the username to access database

Password= password of "Username.Abbreviated" to access database

**and to pass parameter field:**

```
rpt.ParameterFields(1).AddCurrentValue (num)
```

num is my parameter field

[image]